# Libgdx - About 2 player game. I want each player can touch his own area with one finger

Tags: java, libgdx

I am creating 2 players game where each player has his own area. I want each player can touch his own area with one finger. So first I limit to "2 pointers" in the "touchdown" function.

```
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button){
    if(pointer > 1){
        return false;
    }
    Gdx.app.log("", "pointer: "+pointer);

    return false;
}
```

But the problem is if one player touch his own area with his 2 fingers another player won't be able to touch his own area. How can I resolve this problem ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't reject based on the pointer number.

If you want to allow the first pointer down on each side of the screen, you could do something like this (untested):

```
private int player1Pointer = -1, player2Pointer = -1;
private int player1X, player1Y, player2X, player2Y;

//...

public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button){

    // Assuming top and bottom halves of screen:
    if (screenY > Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2){ // player 1 side
        if (player1Pointer >= 0) // player 1 already touching somewhere
            return false;
        player1Pointer = pointer;
        player1X = screenX;
        player1Y = screenY;
    } else { //player 2 side
        if (player2Pointer >= 0) // player 2 already touching somewhere
            return false;
        player2Pointer = pointer;
        player2X = screenX;
        player2Y = screenY;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean touchDragged (int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    if (pointer == player1Pointer){
        player1X = screenX;
        player1Y = screenY;
        return true;
    }
    if (pointer == player2Pointer){
        player2X = screenX;
        player2Y = screenY;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean touchUp (int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    if (pointer == player1Pointer){
        player1Pointer = -1;
        return true;
    }
    if (pointer == player2Pointer){
        player2Pointer = -1;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Great! Your process is better than my process, but it still has some problem. The problem is if my phone has maximum 5 touches, if some player touch his area with 5 fingers(5 touches), so another player won't be able to touch his area. Is there a way to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Nope, there is no way. You also can't stop one of your players from slapping the other in the face to cheat either.

Comment: Is it possible to do this ? If player touch within player 1's area, then Instruct Libgdx to stop generate input event if player touch "another touch" within player 1's area, so "touchdown function" won't be called.

Comment: Don't understand what you're asking but there's no way you can magically make the screen capable of more than its physical limit on number of touches just by ignoring some of the touches.

Comment: Normally when you touch the screen, touchdown function will be called. Can I make touchdown function sometimes will not be called even you touch the screen ? I want to do this. If player first touch his area, then make touchdown function will not be called. So if he touch his area with his second touch, then touchdown function won't be called. If this can be possible, then if some player touch 5 fingers within his area, another player can still touch his area. Hope you understand, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: No, the limit on touches is a hardware limit. Nothing that you do in software can increase the number of simultaneous touches detected.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate ^^

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Simple assume the players play fair and only touch their own areas. Handle the clicks based on which area they hit and then assign the action to the corresponding player number.

If you need pointer index within an area, just assign the pointer number based on the area to player 1 or 2. Delete the assignment when the pointer is touched up. So you always now which pointer numbers is assigned to which player at the current moment.

Assuming pointer 0 is player 1 and pointer 1 is player 2 just does not work.

Comment: Is it possible to do this ?

If player touch within player 1's area, then Instruct Libgdx to stop generate input event if player touch "another touch" within player 1's area, so "touchdown function" won't be called.